# Convert Lotus Notes RichText to PDF programmatically

Tags: java, pdf, lotus-notes, richtext

I want to convert Notes Richtext into PDF in a server program (preferably Java). Is there any sample code how to do that. Converting to HTML/MIME isn't an option since the conversion process is too lossy.

Comment: My current train of thought: use ExportRTF to create MS-RichText and then use a headless OpenOffice install to do the PDF conversion. Might use JODConverter or similar. Eventual DXL2PDF is needed.

Comment: Other train of thought: DXL to FO with discrete Java where XSLT might not suffice (e.g. attachments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some tests with DXL, some XSLT code and XSL:FO, via FOP. It produced some PDF output. Project abandoned due to lack of funding (read: no customer).

The basics, in a recent document: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xslfo/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to find some third-party software to help, as this isn't possible out of the box.  Here's one that looks promising:  [SWING Software's Lotus Notes Export to PDF](http://www.swingsoftware.com/pdf-converter/overview?gclid=CMnvuZ6xia8CFUXc4AodyGCa_Q)

Comment: I just tried to open the [sample package ](http://www.swingsoftware.com/wp-content/uploads/sample-package.pdf) - it wouldn't render in the Chrome PDF viewer thus it isn't PDF-A compliant which is a must-have for long term archival.